# How to avoid freezes while fetching mail in KMail?

Tags: kmail

**Note:** Kmail 1.9.10 from KDE 3.5.10.

KMail has a long story with a bug causing freezes while fetching mail and it lasted even in KDE 4.x series. However if I am not mistaken this is caused by big mailboxes -- and this is not my case.

So, despite using old version of KMail, maybe somebody knows/remembers some trick which could revive the KMail. I can send mail without any problem, however when I try to fetch mail from any of my accounts the last thing UI shows is the info that KMail is trying to fetch mail and that's it -- UI freezes.

Just in case I created sub-mailbox of my inbox and moved half of the mails there. The freeze occurs even if I connect to empty account, so there is no real mail traffic at all.

So how to help KMail unfreeze?

**Update:** I restarted entire computer, on the first run KMail UI was choppy when fetching mail, and it did it way more slowe than usual, but on the second run and later everything got back to normal. So the question still holds -- what caused the freeze. Not the size of the mailbox (local), because now I merged mailboxes as they were before freeze and they still work.